# How to make DOM object mouse movement fluid?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to create a function which can move a page element without having to reference it specifically.

```
    function testmove(obj, event) {
        document.getElementById(obj.id).addEventListener("mousemove", move(obj,event));
    }

    function move(obj, event) {
            document.getElementById(obj.id).innerText = event.clientX + ' ' + event.clientY;
            document.getElementById(obj.id).style.position = 'absolute';
            document.getElementById(obj.id).style.left = event.clientX + "px";
            document.getElementById(obj.id).style.top = event.clientY + "px";
    }
```

This is the original code which worked fluidly:

```
    function testmove(e) {
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', logmovement);
    }

    function logmovement(e) {
        document.getElementById("test").innerText = e.clientX + ' ' + e.clientY;
        document.getElementById("test").style.position = 'absolute';
        document.getElementById("test").style.left = e.clientX + "px";
        document.getElementById("test").style.top = e.clientY + "px";
        mousemove = true;

    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Andy this still results in laggy mouse movement of the object though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're attaching the listener to the element rather than the document so it will only respond when the mouse is positioned on that element.
2. You need to assign a function to the listener. At the moment you're assigning the result of *calling* the `move` function to the listener.

```js
// Pass in the object
function testmove(obj) {

  // Add the listener to the document element as in the
  // working example. Pass a function that calls `move` to the
  // listener.
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", () => move(obj, event));
}

function move(obj, event) {
  document.getElementById(obj.id).innerText = event.clientX + ' ' + event.clientY;
  document.getElementById(obj.id).style.position = 'absolute';
  document.getElementById(obj.id).style.left = event.clientX + "px";
  document.getElementById(obj.id).style.top = event.clientY + "px";
}

const obj = { id: 'move' };

testmove(obj);
```

```html
<div id="move">Move</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! How should I be able to do this where I can define onmousedown="move(this.id)" in reference to the DOM element ID?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you asking how to drag the element and have the same effect?

Comment: Originally I could do a drag and stop event with elements as long as I had their document.getElementById('ID') defined, however, I've wanted to create a move function which accepts their ID from onmousedown input and releases their movement onmouseup input.  I mean, I want to be able to have a dynamic move function where I can pass in the object ID as an argument for it to move that object itself.